# Add to path if in subdir

Tags: path

How can I add a file to the path if the working directory is the directory of the file or one of its subdirectories? So when I'm in `/foo` or in `/foo/bar/` I'll have `/foo/foo.foo` in my path, but if I'm above `/foo` in the tree I won't have it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a builtin way to achieve this, but you could adapt a nifty trick from *Unix Power Tools* (item 14.14 in the second edition). If you're using `bash`, define a function like this

```
cd() {
    builtin cd "$1"
    PATH="$(echo $PATH | sed sX/foo/foo.foo:XXg)"
    if [ "${PWD:0:4}" = "/foo" ]; then
        export PATH="/foo/foo.foo:$PATH"
    fi
}
```

(I don't think it's possible to use a variant of `${PATH//}` to do the replacement since the text we're searching for contains `/`.)

Every time you `cd` somewhere, this will perform the requested change, then remove `/foo/foo.foo` from the path, and finally check if the new current directory is in `/foo`, and prepend `/foo/foo.foo` to the path if it is. By removing `/foo/foo.foo` from the path initially, we avoid having to check whether it's already there before adding it.

To make this complete you'd need to redefine `pushd` and `popd` too...